# pty for root user and sudo commands with grunt-ssh

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-ssh

from [issue 143](https://github.com/israelroldan/grunt-ssh/issues/143) in [grunt-ssh](https://github.com/israelroldan/grunt-ssh) :

I'm trying to perform the following:

1. connect via ssh as a regular user
2. switch to root user and execute a command with privileges, e.g.: ls /root
3. exit root
4. close connection as the regular user (this is could be optional)

I have this configuration

```
sshexec: {
  test: {
    command: [
      'su',  // switch to root user
      'ls /root',  // execute command with privileges
      'exit',  // exit root session
    ],
    options: {
      host: '<%= env.host %>', // host connection
      username: '<%= env.username %>',  // regular user
      password: '<%= env.password %>',  // regular user password
      pty: true,
    }
  }
}
```

> from the docs:
>
> pty :boolean/object

Set to true to allocate a pseudo-tty with defaults, or an object containing specific pseudo-tty settings (see '[Pseudo-TTY settings](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2#pseudo-tty-settings)'). Setting up a pseudo-tty can be useful when working with remote processes that expect input from an actual terminal (e.g. sudo's password prompt).

Apparently there are no ways (or examples at least) to perform what I'm searching for, but I think a use case like this wouldn't be odd to happen.  Is it possible to achieve the above steps with [this](https://github.com/israelroldan/grunt-ssh) library? Can somebody provide more information about a possible pty object configuration, and the advantages/limitations about that?

## Important

Due to security measures on the hosts, I cannot :

1. connect via ssh as root directly
2. pipe the password to sudo command e.g.: "echo  | sudo -S ls /root"

Comment: Give this a try, command: ['<%= env.password %>" | sudo -S  ls /root']

Comment: I've tested and it worked as a charm, it's a good call actuall, but sadlly due to security issues, I'm forced to perform a root ("su") change, and there's when I lost m,y session and I can't do nothing else, I mean after achieved the connection I can run sudo, but the message "Password: " get's prompted, and nothing can be done from there.